# How to return fields depending on RESTful action?

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

I am building a RESTful application in Yii2 and I have overwritten the fields() method in the model (extending ActiveRecord) but I want to define which fields to be returned depending on whether the request was view or list.

It's easy to check in the controller which RESTful action is in use by dumping the $actions variable in the actions method. How can I do something similar in the model? I tried checking the scenario but of course it's `default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several ways, i will describe two of them.

1) Very easy and simple: call `\Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId` in your model's `fields()` method to determine which action is used.

2) According to your comment, *ActionController* define its actions in `actions` method, which returns array of actions and their configurations, e.g. for *view* action:

```
'view' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
    'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
    'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
],
```

so in your child controller you can override parent implementation and set your action classes for each action, like this:

```
public function actions()
{
    $myActions = [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'app\actions\MyViewAction',
        ]
    ];
    return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::actions(), $myActions);
}
```

Here `app\actions\MyViewAction` is your custom action class which you can inherit from `yii\rest\Action` and override `run()` method.

```
public function run($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($this->checkAccess) {
        call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id, $model);
    }
    $model->scenario = 'view';
    return $model;
}
```

and then check scenario in your model and do appropriate actions. Hope this will help

Comment: I should have been more specific and mentioned that the controller extends ActiveController. In this case I don't define any actions and therefore cannot set the scenario.